# How to convert date string to timestamp format in pyspark

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I need to convert string `'07 Dec 2021 04:35:05'` to date format `2021-12-07 04:35:05` in pyspark using dataframe or spark sql.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column full of dates with that format, you can use [`to_timestamp()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp.html) and specify the format according to these [datetime patterns](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html).

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn('new_column', F.to_timestamp('my_column', format='dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'))
```

---

#### Example

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ('07 Dec 2021 04:35:05', ),
  ('31 Dec 2021 06:45:15', )
], ('my_column', ))

df.withColumn('new_column', F.to_timestamp('my_column', format='dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')) \
    .show()
+--------------------+-------------------+
|           my_column|         new_column|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|07 Dec 2021 04:35:05|2021-12-07 04:35:05|
|31 Dec 2021 06:45:15|2021-12-31 06:45:15|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```