# How to convert scalar (string) value to Date type object in pyspark that can be used in filter query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark, so apologize if this is too basic of a question. I have looked at a lot of other StackOverflow posts like ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70921761/how-to-convert-date-string-to-timestamp-format-in-pyspark), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74007217/converting-string-type-date-values-to-date-format-in-pyspark) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75060877/convert-string-to-date-in-pyspark)), but none of the answers there quite fit what I'm trying to do.

I have a dataframe and a string parameter/variable representing dataset date. Using the dataset date, I would like to filter on the dataframe. What I have tried is as below.

```py
customer_panel_s3_location = f"s3://my-bucket/region_id={region_id}/marketplace_id={marketplace_id}/"
customer_panel_table = spark.read.parquet(customer_panel_s3_location)
customer_panel_table.createOrReplaceTempView("customer_panel")
dataset_date = '2023-03-16'
df_customer_panel_table = (
    spark.read.parquet(customer_panel_s3_location)
    .withColumn("dataset_date", dataset_date)
    .filter(col("target_date") < F.to_date(col("dataset_date"), "MM-dd-yyyy"))
)
```

But it returns the following error:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-6b05b499d457> in <module>
     14 
---> 15 df_customer_panel_table = spark.read.parquet(customer_panel_s3_location).withColumn("dataset_date", dataset_date).filter(col("target_date") < F.to_date(col("dataset_date"),"MM-dd-yyyy"))
     16 print(f"{log_prefix} => Physical plan for customer_panel_table\ndf_customer_panel_table.explain()")

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in withColumn(self, colName, col)
   1997 
   1998         """
-> 1999         assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"
   2000         return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc), self.sql_ctx)
   2001
```

I also looked at a [well-known pyspark tutorial site](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-to_date-convert-string-to-date-format/) to see if there's any example of converting a string scalar value to a date type, and use it in a pyspark `filter`. Hoping that someone could share how to do it. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: It should be `.withColumn("dataset_date",F.lit(dataset_date))` - lit is used for literal values for column. Also if you can provide sample data with expected output, it would be easy to help.

Comment: other way of saying what @RonakJain said is: the second param is supposed to be a "column" object, which is more akin to `pandas.Series`.  If you want a literal value then you can use the `pyspark.sql.functions.lit()` function to create a column object out of a literal.

Comment: @RonakJain and @Kashyap - Thank you both! `F.lit(dataset_date)` works like a charm. :) Having said that, I'll accept @DivineCoder's comment below because it was submitted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a date column, use `pyspark.sql.functions.lit` function to wrap your string date literal before passing it to `withColumn`.

So the line that adds a *fixed date* column to your dataframe will look like the following.
(I changed the variable names so it can fit the screen nicely)

```py
...
# see how the following line uses lit
dataset_date = '2023-03-16'
df = df.withColumn("dataset_date", F.lit(dataset_date))
df = df.filter(col("target_date") < F.to_date(col("dataset_date"),"MM-dd-yyyy"))
...
```